# Oracle SQL, separating a Number string to get whole number and decimal separately

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with Oracle SQL, and I have a table with an attribute POST (VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)).  The data that I am given would be in the format 123.34, and I need one VARCHAR2 (123) and one NUMBER (0.34) to store this in a different table.  I was trying to think of a way to do this in a select statement, but could not figure it out.

Comment: So you need to split a string using `.` (dot) as a delimiter?

Comment: Yeah, that would do the trick.  I still don't know how I would do that in Sql though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you be assured that the value will always be a `NUMBER`? If so, then just use `TO_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT '123.34' AS post FROM dual
)
SELECT post_num, TRUNC(post_num), post_num - TRUNC(post_num) FROM (
    SELECT TO_NUMBER(post) AS post_num FROM t1
);
```

---

If you are not sure that it will always be a `NUMBER`, there are "safe" ways of converting a character to a value, e.g., using `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`:

```
TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(post, '^\d*(\.\d+)?'))
```

Comment: `mod(post_num, 1)` would be another way of getting the decimal portion.

Comment: Never would have come up with that on my own, thanks

Answer (score 0):

select '123.45' num,
substr('123.45',1,instr('123.45','.')-1) wholenum,
substr('123.45',instr('123.45','.')+1) decimalpart
from dual

Output:
NUM      WHOLENUM   DECIMALPART
123.45      123          45

Answer (score 0):

Just Floor the Number to get the whole number and reduce the floor value from the number will give the decimal

select 1576.34653 num, floor(1576.34653) whole, 1576.34653-floor(1576.34653) dec
from dual